# Webpack bundling library causing `instanceof` to fail

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, commonjs, instanceof

I'm making a JavaScript library that can accept various plugins from an external library ([`cwl-svg`](https://github.com/rabix/cwl-svg/tree/master/src/plugins)). In this library I want to check what kind of plugin they are, so I use code along the lines of this:

```
import {SVGArrangePlugin} from "cwl-svg";

export default function myFunction(plugins){
    for (plugin of plugins)
        if (plugin instanceof SVGArrangePlugin)
            doSomething();
```

Then, when I build my library, webpack adds the `cwl-svg` library to my bundle, as it should.

---

Now lets say the user of my library writes the following code:

```
import {SVGArrangePlugin} from "cwl-svg";
import func from "my-library";

func([new SVGArrangePlugin()]);
```

The problem is that when the user passes in a plugin to this function with `new SVGArrangePlugin()`, they are passing in an instance of the class from their own version of the `cwl-svg` library, because my library has its own bundled version. Thus, `plugin instanceof SVGArrangePlugin` always returns false, even though `plugin` is identical to an instance of that class.

---

How do I ensure `plugin instanceof SVGArrangePlugin` returns true using webpack? I considered having my library import `cwl-svg` using `externals`, but that seems to be for libraries that export themselves to the window object, when I would rather keep everything contained in my modules. Is there an obvious design decision I'm missing here?

Comment: Ideally you just want one instance of `cwl-svg`.. But if this is not possible you could maybe do ->  `plugin.constructor.name === "SVGArrangePlugin"`

Answer (score 1):

[externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) is exactly what you want. It's not only useful for libraries that export something to the global object, webpack still declares it as an explicit dependency. From the docs:

> The external library may be available in any of these forms:
>
> - root: The library should be available as a global variable (e.g. via a script tag).
> - commonjs: The library should be available as a CommonJS module.
> - commonjs2: Similar to the above but where the export is module.exports.default.
> - amd: Similar to commonjs but using AMD module system.